# Convert PHP encryption code to C#

Tags: c#, .net, php, encryption

I'm trying to convert this piece of code from PHP to C#. It's part of a Captive Portal. Could somebody explain what it does?

```
  $hexchal = pack ("H32", $challenge);
  if ($uamsecret) {
    $newchal = pack ("H*", md5($hexchal . $uamsecret));
  } else {
    $newchal = $hexchal;
  }
  $response = md5("\0" . $password . $newchal);
  $newpwd = pack("a32", $password);
  $pappassword = implode ("", unpack("H32", ($newpwd ^ $newchal)));
```

Comment: I don't see any encryption here... there's no way to decrypt it, because of the hash step

Comment: he doesn't want to decrypt it, just port the code to c#

Comment: I know, I was just pointing out an incorrect use of the term "encryption"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eduardo,

if you take a look at the [pack](http://us.php.net/pack) manual, `pack` is used to convert a string in (hex, octal, binary )to his number representation.

so

```
$hexcal = pack('H32', $challenge);
```

would convert a string like 'cca86bc64ec5889345c4c3d8dfc7ade9' to the actual 0xcca... de9

if $uamsecret exist do the same things with the MD5 of `hexchal` concacteate with the `uamsecret`. 
    if ($uamsecret) {
        $newchal = pack ("H*", md5($hexchal . $uamsecret));
      } else {
        $newchal = $hexchal;
      }

```
$response = md5("\0" . $password . $newchal);
```

MD% '\0' + $password + $newchal

```
$newpwd = pack("a32", $password);
```

pad `password` to 32 byte

```
  $pappassword = implode ("", unpack("H32", ($newpwd ^ $newchal)));
```

do a xor `newpwd` and `newchal` and convert it to a hexadecimal string, I don't get the `implode()` maybe it's to convert to string to an array of character.

Comment: Thanks RageZ. Could you post an input / output example of those pack results?

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the need of php's pack-unpack functions in c# but did not get any good resource.

So i thought to do it myself. I have verified the function's input with pack/unpack/md5 methods found at onlinephpfunctions.com. Since i have done code only as per my requirements. This can be extended for other formats

**Pack**

```
    private static string pack(string input)
    {
        //only for H32 & H*
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(FromHex(input));
    }
    public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
    {
        hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
        byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return raw;
    }
```

**MD5**

```
    private static string md5(string input)
    {
        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
        string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        return hashedString;
    }
```

**Unpack**

```
    private static string unpack(string p1, string input)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            string a = Convert.ToInt32(input[i]).ToString("X");
            output.Append(a);
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
```